# Using version tags for PostgreSQL

Tags: discussion, status-completed, version-tags

We currently have the following tags related to PostgreSQL:

- [postgresql](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postgresql) with 3,042 questions
- [postgresql-10](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postgresql-10) with 27 questions
- [postgresql-9.6](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postgresql-9.6) with 17 questions
- [postgresql-9.5](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postgresql-9.5) with 8 questions

Do we need the version tags or would encouraging users to specify the PostgreSQL version that they are using, when relevant, within the question body, be sufficient?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that for most questions the version doesn't matter, where it does I think adding the version info to the question is sufficient.

Comment: Are you proposing that the three version tags are all made synonyms of, and later merged into, the [tag:postgresql] tag?

Comment: I would second this proposal.

Comment: Yes, synonyms seems to be best

Comment: The three synonyms have now been implemented.